# Creating Binary Response Variable of Customer Churn in R

Tags: r

I have the following excel file:

```
CustomerID  year retained
1   2012    0
2   2013    0
3   2007    1
3   2008    1
3   2009    0
4   2010    0
5   2008    1
5   2009    0
6   2015    0
7   2014    0
8   2010    1
8   2011    1
8   2012    1
8   2013    0
9   2015    0
10  2015    0
```

In excel the command to create the retained variable would be: IF(A2=A3,1,0).

I've read many examples of lapply, sapply, and other things in survival analysis in R on the Internet and on this great site in particular -- but I'm having trouble implementing this in R. I know it'll be something like:

```
df["retained"] <- something
```

I was able to successfully calculate tenure with the following code:

```
df$tenure <- with(df,ave(CustomerID,CustomerID,FUN=seq_along))
```

But I'm having trouble coming up with what the R code for df["retained"] should be, and I've found most of the other Stackoverflow posts more advanced in terms of R.  So hopefully in addition to solving my question, this can help those making the initial transition from excel to R in their efforts too.  Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly unorthodox solution:

```
df$retained <- c(+(df$CustomerID[-1L]==df$CustomerID[-nrow(df)]),0L);
##    CustomerID year retained
## 1           1 2012        0
## 2           2 2013        0
## 3           3 2007        1
## 4           3 2008        1
## 5           3 2009        0
## 6           4 2010        0
## 7           5 2008        1
## 8           5 2009        0
## 9           6 2015        0
## 10          7 2014        0
## 11          8 2010        1
## 12          8 2011        1
## 13          8 2012        1
## 14          8 2013        0
## 15          9 2015        0
## 16         10 2015        0
```

It works by testing if the *next* `CustomerID` is equal to the *previous* `CustomerID`. If true, then the current row (which corresponds to the *previous* `CustomerID`) is retained, and thus should have a value of 1. In (recent versions of) R, you can use the unary plus operator to coerce a logical vector to an integer vector, so applying the unary plus to the result of the equality comparison gives 1 for true and 0 for false.

In addition, we must manually supplement the resulting integer vector with a zero, since the final row does not have a *next* `CustomerID` against which it could be compared.

This solution will only work if the data.frame is ordered by `CustomerID`, and then by `year`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept it as soon as it lets me (I'd upvote it too but I'm too new).  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Since everything is sorted (by both CustomerID and year), you can use `duplicated` with `fromLast` argument:

```
df$retained = as.numeric(duplicated(df$CustomerID, fromLast = T))
```

Comment: Great thank you! Very helpful as well.  Again I'd like to upvote it but I'm too new.  Will be sure to do so in the future though. Thanks!

Comment: You'll be there quickly enough :)

Comment: @Gregor always great

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a simple if else condition. I think it would be something like this

```
for( i in 2:nrow(df)){

if(df[i,1] == df[i-1,1]){
    df[i,3] <- 1}
else 
    {df[i,3] <- 0}}
```

Comment: More r-like to do `df$retained = c(ifelse(df[-1, 1] == df[-nrow(df), 1], 1, 0), 0)`... no for loop needed.

Comment: Simpler for a newbie, dont you think so?